# Adding OpenLayers to rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, openlayers

I have been reading some posts related with this issue, but i couldn't get this working.

I tried to use the 'openlayers-rails' gem and also i tried adding the OpenLayers folder to /vendor/assets/javascript/ (with the require //= require OpenLayers/OpenLayers into the /assets/javascript/application.js file). I both scenarios i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined" as a browser inspector error.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: if you were using the openlayers-rails gem, how were you including the project in your `application.js`?

Comment: As the "usage" section of the gem repo says: https://github.com/tmikoss/openlayers-rails/tree/master

Comment: I've usually had to reboot my Rails servers after adding a new gem. I hope you've tested this by restarting your rails server?

Answer (score 1):

The README for the openlayers-rails gem says that you should include the JS this way:

```
//= require openlayers-rails
```

Not with `//= require OpenLayers/OpenLayers`

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after adding `openlayers-rails` to your `Gemfile`?